# Invalid implicit conversion from address payable to string memory requested

Tags: solidity

I got a compile error `Invalid implicit conversion from address payable to string memory requested` with the code below with solidity 0.6.6
I don't quite understand it.

```
mapping(string => mapping(uint => Sell)) public sells;

mapping(string => uint) public sold;


function sell (string memory _good, string memory _date) public {
    uint sellsCount = sold[_date] ++;
    sells[_date][sellsCount] = Sell(_date, msg.sender, _good, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like when you defined `Sell` struct, you passed the type of address as string. In early versions of Solidity, `msg.sender` was considered as an `address payable`. In `Sell` struct, you should set its type address payable